# Error check value exist in array when use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html

```
    <table id="gwForm">
       <tbody>
          <tr data-id="1"></tr>
          <tr data-id="2"></tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Script

```
var ids = [];
$("#gwForm tbody tr").each(function(index, el){ 
   ids.push($(el).data('id')); 
});

var id = 3; //=1 or =2
if($.inArray(id, ids) != -1) {
   alert("the element is not in the array");
} else {
   alert("the element in the array");
}
```

When id=3 (or =2) result is `the element is not in the array`. How to fix it ?

Comment: your "!= -1" should just be "== -1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your condition backwards.

```
if($.inArray(id, ids) != -1) {
   alert("the element is not in the array");
} else {
   alert("the element in the array");
}
```

Should be

```
if($.inArray(id, ids) > -1) {
   alert("the element is in the array");
} else {
   alert("the element is not in the array");
}
```